# force recompilation of war file including its Jar dependencies

Tags: java, web-applications, maven

I have a project A (a webapp), depending on project B (B.jar) and this one depending on project C (C.jar).

I would like to create a maven goal named "Rebuild War", that clean all compiled code for these 3 projects and rebuild the whole in order to obtain a fresh War file.

I tried mvn clean package on project A, but I noticed that B and C are not recompiled. Indeed,  B.jar and C.jar that are contained in local repository don't have a changing creation date.

Is there an adapted maven command for this requirement ?

Comment: You didn't give your "anemic beans" question much of a chance, did you?  30 minutes is not very long to wait for an answer on the weekend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a directory structure of

```
/foo/A/pom.xml
/foo/B/pom.xml
/foo/C/pom.xml
```

you need to introduce

```
/foo/pom.xml
```

and that should specify A, B and C as modules.  You can now do `cd /foo; mvn clean install` and have A, B, and C recompiled.  If your dependencies are correct, they even do so in the correct order.

Comment: Thanks, that works well ! Your answer allowed me to read several articles about multiprojects module ;)